# PTIJ: Is the Milky Way Cholov Yisroel?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What are some sources that the Milky Way is Cholov Yisroel?

Assuming Avraham Avinu was the first Jew, who was the Mashgiach from Adam to Terach?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: משגיח מן החלנות

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely not Chalav Yisra'el. If you look up at the sky, it appears "crooked" because it's not in a perfectly straight line.

Thus, it is considered חלב עקום - crooked milk.

Comment: Nice. Very punny...

Comment: @Harel13 Thanks to an Israeli friend of mine who mentioned this pun to me about 40 years ago. I have a feeling that many readers won't understand my answer, though.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [London Beth Din](https://isitkosher.uk/#milky%20way), Milky Way is certified as kosher, but not chalav yisrael.

Answer (score 2):

"Milky way" in Hebrew is "Shvil Hachalav" שביל החלב, which in Gimatriyah equals "הודו לה' כי טוב, כי לעולם חסדו".
From this we learn two things:

1. The Milky way is good, and since kosher food is also good (as the late Moshe Yess said "[Kosher meat just can't be beat](http://www.mosheyess.ca/chords/Moshe-Yess-Megama-Throw-Away-That-Ham.pdf)", kal v'chomer other Kosher foods), we can therefore surmise that the Milky way is Kosher. And since the gimatriyah is in Hebrew, it must be that Milky way is made from Israeli milk, which is Chalav Yisrael.

and subsequently,

2. We are thankful for the good that Hashem gave us, e.g. the Milky way. From this we can conclude that the first mashgiach of the Milky way was Hashem, before handing over the duties to Avraham, as it is said ([Taanit 2a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.2a.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)):

   > ג' מפתחות בידו של הקב"ה...נמסרו ביד שליח ואלו הן מפתח של גשמים מפתח של חיה מפתח של תחיית המתים...במערבא אמרי אף מפתח של פרנסה דכתיב (תהלים קמה, טז) פותח את ידך וגו' ור' יוחנן מאי טעמא לא קא חשיב להא אמר לך גשמים היינו פרנסה

Translation: 3 keys were in Hashem's hand, passed over to a messenger, and these are: the key of rain, the key of life and the key of the resurrection...in Maarava they said, also the key of parnasah...and Rabbi Yochanan why didn't he include that [key]? He'd say to you, rain is parnasah.

Meaning Hashem handed over three keys, including the key of parnasah, to Avraham, His first messenger - or in other words, he gave him His job as mashgiach of the Milky way, for parnasah.

Comment: I can’t reconcile your Gematrios. שביל החלב is 387, while הודו וגו׳ is 408. Even if I presume עם הכולל עם התיבות ועם האותיות on שביל החלב, that only gets it up to 398.

Comment: @DonielF Shem Hashem is just the letter ה in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Aruch Hashulchan Yoreh Deah 92:49 explains that there is not much milk in the Milky Way, so I would therefore assume that the milk in it is Batel, and it is considered Pareve:

> דאדרבא מפני **שהחלב מעט כ"דרך החלב"** הנשפך בתנור שאין הרבה חלב בכמות על מקום אחד, אין בכחו להבליע בכולי קדירה
>
> The opposite is true, **since the milk is a small quantity, as in a milky way [chocolate bar]**, if [that entire amount of] milk would spill in an oven, and there would not be a lot of milk in one place, it would not be enough to be absorbed by the whole pot.

Answer (score 1):

Since hashem made the milky-way, we can assume that it's kosher since we're told in Psalm 62:8 to:
"Trust in him at all times"

Comment: That just makes it Chalav Stam.

Comment: You're assuming that Hashem's hashgacha is trustworthy. That's not the best assumption. Remember - *Lo Bashamayim Hi* - "It's not in heaven".

Comment: @DanF wouldn't lo bashamayim hi only be relevant post-giving-of-the-Torah? In which case Hashem's hashgacha is at least relevant until that time?

Comment: @DanF the Milky Way is _bashomayim hi_

Answer (score -1):

Ah you mean from the bedtime prayer

```
May Michael be at my right hand,
Gabriel at my left hand,
Before me Raphael and
Behind me Uriel,
And above me Israel Shekinah.
```

or in a short version

```
A la derecha Mihael,
I a la siedra Gabriel, 
Sovre la kavesa Shehina de El
Kada dia i kada noche
```

The four corners are four stars. Put Aldebaran and Antares to your sides, Formalhault in the south to your back, look above "over your head" and you will see the summer triangle and, crossing it, the Milky Way.

[image]

So, in the same sense that the other stars are Michael Gabriel Uriel etc, the Milky Way is Israel Shekinah